# How to indicate each face of a 3D rotatable Cube in OpenGL 2.0, Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I created a 3D rotatable cube using OpenGL2.0. Now I want it to show the name of each face if we touch a particular face. For example, we rotate the cube and show the bottom face as the front. Then we touch or click this face, a prompt will appear and tell us that it is the "bottom face".

Anybody has an idea of how to do this? Since I just need this simple feature, if the solution is easy, that would be better. Thank you so much!

```
public class MyCube {
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
private ShortBuffer[] ArrayDrawListBuffer;
private FloatBuffer colorBuffer;

private int mProgram;

//For Projection and Camera Transformations
private final String vertexShaderCode =
        // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
        // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                //"attribute vec4 vColor;" +
                //"varying vec4 vColorVarying;" +
                "void main() {" +
                // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
                // Note that the uMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
                // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                //"vColorVarying = vColor;"+
                "}";

// Use to access and set the view transformation
private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                //"varying vec4 vColorVarying;"+
                "void main() {" +
                //"  gl_FragColor = vColorVarying;" +
                "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                "}";

// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
float cubeCoords[] = {
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,   // front top left 0
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,   // front bottom left 1
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,   // front bottom right 2
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,  // front top right 3
        -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,   // back top left 4
        0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,   // back top right 5
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,   // back bottom left 6
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  // back bottom right 7
        };


// Set color with red, green, blue and alpha (opacity) values
float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f };
float red[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
float blue[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };

private short drawOrder[][] = {
                                {0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3},//front
                                {0, 4, 5, 0, 5, 3}, //Top
                                {0, 1, 6, 0, 6, 4}, //left
                                {3, 2, 7, 3, 7 ,5}, //right
                                {1, 2, 7, 1, 7, 6}, //bottom
                                {4, 6, 7, 4, 7, 5} //back
                                }; //(order to draw vertices)


final float cubeColor3[][] =
        {
                // Front face (red)
                {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},

                // Top face (green)
                {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},

                // Left face (blue)
                {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},

                // Right face (yellow)
                {1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},

                // Bottom face (cyan)
                {0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},

                // Back face (magenta)
                {1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}
        };



public MyCube() {
    // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
           cubeCoords.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(cubeCoords);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);


    int vertexShader = MyRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
            vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = MyRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
            fragmentShaderCode);

    // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

    // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);

    // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);

    // creates OpenGL ES program executables
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);
}

private int mPositionHandle;
private int mColorHandle;

private final int vertexCount = cubeCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) { // pass in the calculated transformation matrix


    // Draw the cube
    for (int face = 0; face < 6; face++) {

        // Add program to OpenGL ES environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
        // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member

        //mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

        // Enable a handle to the cube vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        // Prepare the cube coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
        // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
        ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
                drawOrder[face].length * 2);
        dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
        drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder[face]);
        drawListBuffer.position(0);

        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, cubeColor3[face], 0);

        // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");

        // Pass the projection and view transformation to the shader
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder[face].length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);
    }


    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mMVPMatrixHandle);
  }
}
```

Renderer:

```
public class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{

private MyCube mCube;

// mMVPMatrix is an abbreviation for "Model View Projection Matrix"
private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
//create another transformation matrix (a rotation matrix)
private float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];

/** Store the accumulated rotation. */
private final float[] mAccumulatedRotation = new float[16];
/** Store the current rotation. */
private final float[] mCurrentRotation = new float[16];
/** Create a temporary matrix. */
private final float[] mTemporaryMatrix = new float[16];



public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
    // Set the background frame color
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // initialize a square
    mCube = new MyCube();

    // Initialize the accumulated rotation matrix
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mAccumulatedRotation, 0);
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
    // Redraw background color
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    float[] scratch = new float[16];
    // Create a rotation transformation for the square
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mRotationMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mCurrentRotation, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(mCurrentRotation, 0, mDeltaX, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.rotateM(mCurrentRotation, 0, mDeltaY, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    mDeltaX = 0.0f;
    mDeltaY = 0.0f;

    // Multiply the current rotation by the accumulated rotation, and then set the accumulated
    // rotation to the result.
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mTemporaryMatrix, 0, mCurrentRotation, 0, mAccumulatedRotation, 0);
    System.arraycopy(mTemporaryMatrix, 0, mAccumulatedRotation, 0, 16);

    // Rotate the cube taking the overall rotation into account.
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mTemporaryMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, mAccumulatedRotation, 0);
    System.arraycopy(mTemporaryMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, 16);



    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, -2, 2, 5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    //Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

    // Combine the rotation matrix with the projection and camera view
    // Note that the mMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
    // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
    Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);

    // Draw shape
    mCube.draw(scratch);
}


@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    float ratio = (float) width / height;

    // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
    // in the onDrawFrame() method
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
}

public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

    // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

    // add the source code to the shader and compile it
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

    return shader;
}

public volatile float mDeltaX;
public volatile float mDeltaY;
}
}
```

MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private MyGLSurfaceView mGLView;

public void showToast(final String toast) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create a GLSurfaceView instance and set it
    // as the ContentView for this Activity.
    mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(mGLView);

    //LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("hello world");
    //ll.addView(b);
    //ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    this.addContentView(b,
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
}
```

MyGLSurfaceView.java

```
public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

private final MyRenderer mRenderer;

private final float TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR = 180.0f / 320;
private float mPreviousX;
private float mPreviousY;


float touchedX = 0;
float touchedY = 0;


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // MotionEvent reports input details from the touch screen
    // and other input controls. In this case, you are only
    // interested in events where the touch position changed.

    if (event != null) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

            if (mRenderer != null) {
                float deltaX = (x - mPreviousX) / 2f;
                float deltaY = (y - mPreviousY) / 2f;

                mRenderer.mDeltaX += deltaX;
                mRenderer.mDeltaY += deltaY;
                mRenderer.mTotalDeltaX += mRenderer.mDeltaX;
                mRenderer.mTotalDeltaY += mRenderer.mDeltaY;
                mRenderer.mTotalDeltaX = mRenderer.mTotalDeltaX % 360;
                mRenderer.mTotalDeltaY = mRenderer.mTotalDeltaY % 360;

            }
            requestRender();
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (event.getX() < 950f && event.getX() > 150f && event.getX() < 1300f && event.getX() > 400f) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", Float.toString(mRenderer.mTotalDeltaX) + " " + Float.toString(mRenderer.mTotalDeltaY));
                Log.d("DEBUG", Float.toString(event.getX()) + " " + Float.toString(event.getY()));
//***Here is where I want to add toast*** Thank you so much!///

            } else {

            }
        }


        mPreviousX = x;
        mPreviousY = y;

        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}






public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context){
    super(context);

    // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

    mRenderer = new MyRenderer();

    // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
    setRenderer(mRenderer);

    // Render the view only when there is a change in the drawing data.
    // To allow the Square to rotate automatically, this line is commented out:
    //setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide some code on how you implemented your rotation of the cube. I may have a simple answer, but that depends on how you chose to do the rotation.

Comment: Hi, I added my code up there, please have a look. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears in your code that you have,

```
mDeltaX;
mDeltaY;
```

which act as temporary variables for rotating the cube (you reset them to 0.0 each frame). 
In addition to these variables, create two variables,

```
mTotalDeltaX;
mTotalDeltaY;
```

and instead of resetting them to 0.0, let them accumulate the entire change in X and change in Y.

With these variables, you now know how much you have rotated totally relative to the X-axis and Y-axis. Now, you just need to use several if-statements based on these two variables to determine which face is currently in view.

For example, if

```
mTotalDeltaX = 0.0;
mTotalDeltaY = 0.0;
```

you know that you are looking at the 1st face of the cube, since it hasn't been rotated at all.

If you are unable to determine what values of mTotalDeltaX and mTotalDeltaY would give you the correct face, I suggest that you use logcat to help you as you figure out what values of mTotalDeltaX and mTotalDeltaY show which faces. Put this line in onDrawFrame():

```
Log.d("DEBUG", Float.toString(mTotalDeltaX) + " " + Float.toString(mTotalDeltaY));
```

As you rotate your cube, look at your logcat and see what mTotalDeltaX and mTotalDeltaY are. Record these numbers down, and create a series of if statements accordingly.

Important note: Use the modulus operator to prevent mTotalDeltaX and mTotalDeltaY from being negative or over 360 degrees. This will allow to use if statements within that range. For example, after you have updated mTotalDeltaX and mTotalDeltaY,

```
mTotalDeltaX += mDeltaX;
mTotalDeltaY += mDeltaY;
```

apply the modulus operator,

```
mTotalDeltaX = mTotalDeltaX % 360;
mTotalDeltaY = mTotalDeltaY % 360;
```

EDIT: In response to your new question below, to make a Toast in when ACTION_DOWN is detected:

At the bottom of your MyGLSurfaceView.java, you have the context being passed as a parameter. Save that context, into another context variable,

```
Context myContext;

public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context){
super(context);
myContext = context;

// Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context
setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

mRenderer = new MyRenderer();

// Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
setRenderer(mRenderer);

// Render the view only when there is a change in the drawing data.
// To allow the Square to rotate automatically, this line is commented out:
//setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
}
```

Now, in your ACTION_DOWN, where you have commented that you want your toast,

```
Toast.makeText(myContext, "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Great idea! Many Thanks! In addition, if I want to use 'Toast.makeText()' when 'MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN' to show which face is in the front. Where should I add the Toast? Because I have MyActivity.java, MyRenderer.java, MyGLSurfaceView.java. Thanks again.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html. A context is required, I would assume that you could do this easiest in MyActivity.java, if that is the activity that is running during the rendering of your scene. You would just write Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show().

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. However, the onTouchEvent which can detect motion is under MyGLSurfaceView.java. Toast can be shown now but not when 'ACTION_DOWN'. This maybe considered as multi threading, and that is what my confusion is.

Comment: I would have to see some code, but you can pass your context to MyGLSurfaceView.java, and then write your toast in there too when ACTION_DOWN is triggered...unless I'm misunderstanding the problem

Comment: Hi Bro, I believe you got my question. I have added my code of MyActivity.java and MyGLSurfaceView.java up there and highlighted where to add toast.  Please take a look.

Comment: It's totally working now! Thank you so much! You are awesome!